# How exactly is axiom of dependent choice used in Baire's Theorem?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I went over the proof of Baire's Theorem for complete metric spaces (that a countable union of closed sets with empty interior has empty interior). In the proof, a decreasing nested sequence of closed balls is constructed. Then we choose a particular point from each of these balls and construct a sequence of those points.

I thought that we used axiom of choice when we chose these points. But then I read in multiple source that we actually don't use axiom of choice and that we use a weaker form, called the axiom of dependent choice. I looked up the definition of dependent choice:

Axiom of dependent choice (DC): Let $A$ be a non-empty set and $R \subseteq A \times A$ satisfy $\forall a \in A \; \exists b \in A: a R b$. Then there exists a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_n \; R \; a_{n+1} \; \forall n$.

The problem I have with this is that I don't understand how this axiom was used. First of all, what is the set $A$ and relation $R$ when we apply DC to prove Baire's Theorem? And secondly, could someone explain in some more details how this axiom is used.

Comment: I wrote a whole chapter about it: https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15632

Comment: And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4258931/using-dc-to-prove-baires-category-theorem-in-munkres) might also answer your question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila is it possible to prove Baire's Theorem for locally compact hausdorff spaces without DC? If so, could you refer me to a proof that doesn't use it? (I know it isn't possible for complete metric spaces, because they are equivalent).

Comment: Well, assuming BPI it is equivalent to to DC, so you can't. See https://mathoverflow.net/a/391946/7206

Comment: Can you share the exact proof that you saw?

Answer (score -1):

Define a sequence of points $x_n$ such that $x_{n+1}$ is within $2^{-n}$ of $x_n$. We're applying DC to the relation "$x_{n+1}$ is within $2^{-n}$ of $x_n$". (This answer uses some help from the text that Asaf Karagila linked in the comments, but I have not yet read its explanation of why DC is enough.)

Answer (score -1):

The following depends on [https://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/Courses/MeasCategory/lect4.pdf](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Etsirel/Courses/MeasCategory/lect4.pdf)

By using DC, we can show the following (Lemma 4c1 in the above reference. A proof is given.):

Claim: Let $A_0, A_1, \cdots$ be a sequence of non-empty sets. Assume that for each $n \ge 0$, there exists a subset $R_n$ of $A_n \times A_{n+1}$ such that for every $x \in A_n$ there exists $y \in A_{n+1}$ such that $(x,y) \in R_n$. Then, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that $(x_n, x_{n+1}) \in R_n$ for each $n \ge 0$.

Let $(U_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of dense open subsets of a complete metric space $(M,d)$. Let $U$ be a non-empty open subset of $M$. It suffices to show that $U \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n$ is non-empty.

Notation: For $A \subset M$, $\text{diam}(A) := \sup_{x, y \in A} d(x,y)$ and $\overline{A}$ is  the closure of $A$.

We apply the claim to the  case that $A_n$ is the set of open balls of $U \cap U_1 \cap \cdots \cap U_n$ and  $R_n = \{(B,B^{\prime}) \in A_n \times A_{n+1} : \text{diam}(B^{\prime}) < \text{diam}(B)/2, \overline{B^{\prime}} \subset B \}$. Since $U_n$ is dense for each $n$,  $A_n$ is non-empty for each  $n$. Let $B \in A_n$.  Then, $B \cap U_{n+1}$ is a non-empty open subset of $M$, and hence, there exists an open ball  $B^{\prime}$ of $B \cap U_{n+1}$ such that $(B, B^{\prime}) \in R_{n}$.

Now, by the claim, there exists  a sequence $(B_n)_n$ of open balls such that  $(B_n, B_{n+1}) \in R_n$. Let $x_n$ be the center of $B_n$. Then, $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$. By the completeness, there exists a limit $x_{\infty} \in M$. We will show that  $x_{\infty} \in U \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n$. Let $U_0 := U$. Let $n \ge 0$. Then, for every $m > n$, $x_m \in B_{m} \subset \overline{B_{n+1}}$. Hence, $x_{\infty} \in \overline{B_{n+1}} \subset B_n$.

$(x_n)_n$ need not to be the centers. When we pick an infinite sequence, we use the axiom of countable choice, which follows from DC.